# Boostrap 5 collapse set show instead of toggle and allow anchor execution

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Is there a way via the html attributes to have a link that will only "open" a collapsible target (if it's already open then just just stays open) and anchor link to it with the hashtag.

When I add "data-bs-toggle" my anchor href="#dashboard-VC" doesn't work.
`<a class="btn" href="#dashboard-VC" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dash-VC">{{NAME}}</a>`

I can add this JS to move the screen but I wanted to avoid having to add this if there's a way to tell BS5 to allow the click event to bubble through without writing extra JS
`<a class="btn" href="#dashboard-VC" onclick="document.getElementById('dashboard-VC').scrollIntoView();" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dash-VC">{{NAME}}</a>`

Now the next one is I want this to only "open" the collapsible area not toggle it. This button is a shortcut at the top of the page that will scrolldown to bring this area into view and "open" it if it's not already open. I can write JS to do everything but I was hoping to keep it all JS free and just use BS5 HTML attributes to handle it but not sure if that's possible.

I tried data-bs-toggle="open" but that's not a thing hoping it just wasn't documented. Maybe there's something other then the collapse competent that would handle this better?

Here is a working example but all in JS which is what I wanted to avoid having in the code: `<a class="btn" href="#dashboard-VC" onclick="document.getElementById('dashboard-VC').scrollIntoView();document.getElementById('dash-VC').classList.add('show')">{{NAME}}</a>`

Thanks.